# React Router v4 NavLink not working unless the container component is a child of <Route/> or wrapped with withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm migrating my app from React Router v3 to v4.
While I'm changing `Link` components to `NavLink` components, I noticed that the `activeClassName` prop is not being added anymore. The Component containing the `NavLink`s is not a direct child of a `Route` component, so the component doesn't re-render. When I decorate the component using `withRouter`, the component re-renders and `activeClassName` props are added. Is this intentional? Or have I missed anything?

Simply put:

```
class Container extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavLink to='/path/to/page' activeClassName='active'>Click Me</NavLink>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

.. doesn't work unless I export it like:

```
export default withRouter(Container);
```